# What parameters to check for connection is "dirty" / leaking

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to develop unit testing framework. I want to know if current connection is leaking. I want to check if previous stored procedure/function/sql executed is not leaking anything.

- There is no pending transaction for current connection
- pg_advisory_lock
- There is no temp table remaining to be deleted for current connection

**What else I should check**

I know there is `DISCARD ALL` which reset everything, but I want to know if current connection is leaking anything and what it is leaking?

Answer (score 0):

This is what DISCARD ALL does:

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION DEFAULT;
RESET ALL;
DEALLOCATE ALL;
CLOSE ALL;
UNLISTEN *;
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock_all();
DISCARD PLANS;
DISCARD SEQUENCES;
DISCARD TEMP;
```

So you may also have:

- user identifiers in the session
- session parameters
- prepared statements
- opened cursors
- notification channels
- cached plans
- cached sequences